# Pick M elements from array such that maximum of all is minimum

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Given an array `A` of boxes such that each box contains some balls in it
and `ith` box has `A[i]` number of balls. we have to pick `M` balls from any box such that the maximum balls of all boxes should be minimum

for example `A = [1,9,3,7,5,6,4,8,2]` and `M = 6`
than we will pick `3 balls from 2nd box`, `2 balls from 8th box`, and `1 ball from 4th box`
and the final array will look like `A = [1,6,3,6,5,6,4,6,2]`

Which algorithm should I use?

```
1 < A[i] < 1e9
1 < M < 1e18
```

Comment: Sort descending. Reduce the first element so it equals the second. Reduce 1st and 2nd to equal the third, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , there is no standard algorithm to use for you problem so
 I will explain the way this should be solved.

The problem requires
 you to find modify the array so that you will obtain the minimum
 possible oft of the "max boxes".     The key here is to find the
 maximum of your array and to extract a ball from it every time and, at
 the same time, lower the M by 1. This action should be repeated while
 M !=0. Using your example,the steps would look like this:

A = [1,9,3,7,5,6,4,8,2]
A = [1,8,3,7,5,6,4,8,2]
A = [1,7,3,7,5,6,4,8,2]
A = [1,7,3,7,5,6,4,7,2]
A = [1,6,3,7,5,6,4,7,2]
A = [1,6,3,6,5,6,4,7,2]
A = [1,6,3,6,5,6,4,6,2]

If you still have some questions, feel free to
 ask! I can also provide you with a full working algorithm but you
 should try to create it yourself first!

Comment: Extracting a single ball will take too much time for the large value of `M` I have updated the range of `M` in question. Can I use binary search here?

Comment: Well, you can.But in order to aply binary search, you must first sort the array.And, since you sort it, there is no need for search here.If you sort them  descending, you can reduce the value of the first till it's smaller than the second element and so on.